# apxproof and formatting titles

Tags: amsthm

I'm currently working with the `apxproof` package and I'm having some minor trouble with it... Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{apxproof}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Some test title] Some other nonsense.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

which produces this
[image]
but what I actually would want is 
[image]
If I comment out the line with `\usepackage{apxproof}` I get what I want, but I'm obviously not able any more to use the package... So, is there a way to keep using the package and make the title of the Definitions (and Theorems etc.) appear as defined in `\theoremstyle` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `apxproof` package does

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\thmhead#1#2#3{%
    \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
    \thmnote{ #3}}%
}
```

which is the cause of the issue.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{apxproof}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheoremrep{definition}{Definition}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\thmhead#1#2#3{%
    \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
    \thmnote{ {\normalfont (#3)}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Some test title]
Some other nonsense.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]